# Asp.Net MVC download varbinary stored in database as file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i want to download varbinary stored in database as a file. I am able to download the file, however all the file that downloaded from my application are unable to open. I noticed that i upload pdf file with size 200 kb. But when i download that file, its only return 30 byte.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(Upload model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, String random_number, String rcf_number)
    {
        var db = new RCFOnlineEntities();
        if(uploadFile != null)
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(uploadFile.InputStream))
            {
                bytes = br.ReadBytes(uploadFile.ContentLength);
            }

            model.file_base6 = bytes;
            model.file_ext = uploadFile.ContentType;
            model.file_name = uploadFile.FileName;
            model.rcfnumber = rcf_number;
            model.randomnumber = random_number;
        }

      

        db.Uploads.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "GetRCFOnline", new { random_number = random_number });
    }

[HttpGet]
   public FileResult DownLoadFile(int id, String random_number)
   {

      List<Upload> ObjFiles = GetUploadClasses(random_number);

      var FileById = (from FC in ObjFiles
                       where FC.file_id.Equals(id)
                       select new { FC.file_name, FC.file_base6 , FC.file_ext}).ToList().FirstOrDefault();


    
      return File(FileById.file_base6, FileById.file_ext, FileById.file_name);

   }
```

Could you tell me where is the error within my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution-1:**

Use **uploadFile.InputStream.Length** instead **uploadFile.ContentLength** for correct upload file size i.e.

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(uploadFile.InputStream))
{
     bytes = br.ReadBytes(uploadFile.InputStream.Length);
}
```

**Solution-2:**

If BinaryReader is not a fixed requirement then use below solution to get uploaded file's bytes i.e.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[uploadFile.InputStream.Length];
uploadFile.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: its says "cannot convert from long to int"

Comment: if you need your stream in bytes  and BinaryReader is not a fixed requirement then you can simply use solution-2 I have updated in my above answer.